# Service Workers creation issue: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I am trying to create my first service workers (having put my local server off-line to test that state). I have written code below at the top of one file called app.js:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("serviceworker.js")
    .then(function(registration){
        console.log("Service Worker registered with scope:", registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("Service Worker registration failed:", err);
    });
}
```

Then in the serviceworker.js file I have:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event){
    if (event.request.url.includes("bootstrap.min.css")) {
    event.respondWith(
        new Response(
            ".hotel-slogan {background: green!important;} nav { display:none }",
            { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/css" }}
        )
        );
    }
});
```

This is what I am getting on the web page:

This site can’t be reached

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> Search Google for localhost 8443
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And this is the message I am seeing in the Chrome console:

> 07:42:35.401 Navigated to chrome-error://chromewebdata/
>
> 07:42:36.453 An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
>
> 07:42:36.453 localhost:8443/serviceworker.js Failed to load resource:
>
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your question? :-)

This is completely normal. If you're trying to get your site available offline, that SW script it is not doing it for you. What your SW does is this: if a client controlled by the SW requests bootstrap.min.css, the SW responds with that string in the code. Otherwise it doesn't do anything.

If your aim is to cache the site, then you have to do that. Now the SW is not doing it.

I suggest you read [Google's Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) guide on the topic and check some working examples from [serviceworke.rs](https://serviceworke.rs/). **You should really read the guide** and not just start hacking some code together – **there are an awful many things to miss that could lead to all kinds of bugs**.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete! Helpful. I will indeed follow your advice. I am actually expecting a SW registration or at least a message saying SW registration failed. But instead the message I am getting as you can see says it is failing to load the resource. No connection. My goal is to register the SW first before attempting anything else.